# How to send authenticated request to Discogs Api

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, discogs-api

I'm following the [OAuth 1.0 Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849)  so I can send an Authenticated Request to /oauth/identity Endpoint as in step 5 of the [Auth flow](http://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:authentication,header:authentication-oauth-flow).

From the doc, making request involves including several params as you can see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.1).

What my requests looks like is :

```
http://api.discogs.com/oauth/identity?
oauth_consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY&
oauth_nonce=1453720099377&
oauth_signature=CONSUMER_SECRET&ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET&
oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&
oauth_timestamp=1453720099377&
oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

where ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET derive from step 4 of the Auth Flow guide and
CONSUMER_SECRET and CONSUMER_KEY from my Discogs developer settings.

What my code looks in Java, since this is for an android Discogs client :

```
public void getIdentity() {
    httpClient.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"").append(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY).append("\",");
    stringBuilder.append("oauth_nonce=\"").append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).append("\",");
    stringBuilder.append("oauth_signature=\"").append(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET).append(authAccessSecretToken).append("\",");
    stringBuilder.append("oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\",");
    stringBuilder.append("oauth_timestamp=\"").append(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).append("\",");
    stringBuilder.append("oauth_token=\"").append(authAccessToken).append("\"");
    httpClient.addHeader("Authorization", stringBuilder.toString());
    httpClient.addHeader("User-Agent", "Discs/1.0 +https://jb.com");
    httpClient.get(identityURL, null, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, String s, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure IDENTITY " + i + "  Throwable = " + throwable);
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure IDENTITY " + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String s) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess IDENTITY -- String= " + s);
        }
    });

}
```

But what I get is :  {"message": "You must authenticate to access this resource."}

Answer (score -2):

Using an OAuth library instead of generating these requests manually will likely save you a headache. more information read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#page-14

Comment: he was asking because he wants to write his own. Super not helpful answer.